# Sorting a list based on integer

Tags: c#, list, int

I've set a public list.

```
public List<Image> imageList { get; set; }
```

I've created a class for this image

```
//Creating a public class for image.
public class Image
{
    //Setting the types of data that we want to store.
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public string ImageName { get; set; }
    public int OrderRank { get; set; }

    // Pass through the data.
    public Image(string url, string imageName, int orderRank)
    {
        //Setting the data.
        Url = url;
        ImageName = imageName;
        OrderRank = orderRank;

    }

}
```

I'm adding data into the list, this is all adding fine.

```
//Passing through the data.
Image image  = new Image(imgSource, imgName, orderRank);

//Adding to image list
this.imageList.Add(image);
```

My list is populating fine, this is what it looks like, 
[image: img]

What i'm trying to do is order this list by OrderRank, so 1,2,3 etc.

Is this possible at the moment i've tried this method but having no luck.

```
var sorted = imageList.OrderBy(h => h.OrderRank);
```

Here you can see my full code - https://dotnetfiddle.net/TZH9B9

Comment: You're saying that last statement there doesn't work?

Comment: It should just work

Comment: Hasn't he already answered his question there?

Comment: Yes the var sorted is coming back as null

Comment: `OrderBy` returns an IEnumerable, so you have to expand that to see the results. It does not return null.

Comment: Not likely that it returns as null. Can you post a more complete section of your code? Maybe you are assigning null to it somewhere or some problems with where you are doing it - in which scopes

Comment: Thanks for your responses, I have added my full code

Comment: Have you considered making your `sorted` variable a List<Image> instead of var ?

Comment: Thanks what i think i'm going to do now

Comment: hey @ryan, which variable are you inspecting when you are checking if it is ordered properly or not? Are you checking the "imageList" variable or the "sorted" variable?

Comment: @sam alot of people confuse c# var with VB variant

Comment: the sorted variable, i've linked my full code